# Fire Store's on_snapshot() function in Python executes twice. How to make it execute once?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, google-cloud-firestore

This is my callback that executes when a user is added to a collection

```
# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot_user(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print(u'Callback received query snapshot user.')
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            doc = change.document.to_dict()
            email = doc["email"]
            group = doc["survey_group"]
            gender = doc["survey_gender"]
            age = doc["survey_age"]
            userInfo = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            if userInfo is None:
                User.insert(User(email))
                userInfo = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            userInfo.group = group
            userInfo.gender = gender
            userInfo.age = age
            User.update(userInfo)
```

email is a primary key. When a user is added to Firestore, this triggers twice and it gives an error of a duplicate key.
How do I make this execute once in Python as metadata.PendingWrites is not yet supported in Python?
I am developing in Flask. I'm new to it so would appreciate any kind of help.

Edit:
Some context - I am adding the data I get to a PostgreSQL database. I am planning to do so as I need to build a kind of leaderboard and I'm planning to store the user info + their points in a postgreSQL table.

Comment: posted an answer , Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps to resolve multiple execution issue :

**1**.  First would be to create a doc reference variable for the document you want to execute.
Create a doc_ref variable for the document you want to populate.

**Syntax** :  doc_ref = db.Collection(collection_name)

**2**.  Second step would be to watch the document.
doc_watch would be the variable created for watching the document.

**Syntax** : doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot_functionName(on_snapshot_functionName)

**3**.  Third step would be to Terminate watch on the document so it will be executed once.
You can use unsubscribe() to terminate the watch.

**Syntax** : doc_watch.unsubscribe()

For further details related to real time updates in Cloud Firestore, you can refer to the documentation [1].

[1] : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen